# AEM code and content migration from AEM 5.6.1 to AEM 6.1

Tags: migration, upgrade, aem

We have 3-4 application in AEM 5.6.1 and now we are migrating one of the applications to AEM 6.1. 
We will be creating packages of application from 5.6.1 and deploying them to new instance AEM 6.1.

Is it all we need to do ?

Or else we require any other steps or modifications also ?

Answer (score 3):

Since AEM 6.1 removes support for CRX2, you must first migrate the repository to Apache Oak before upgrading if you are using an AEM 5.x or AEM 6.0 with a CRX2 backend installation.

This [doc](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/upgrade.html) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with yours components and code may be founded.
You may find additional iformation on [Adobe Upgrade page](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/upgrade.html)

Answer (score 0):

Moving package will do the trick, but you have to check if you are using any deprecated methods which might let your code to fail.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I had come across:

- Do the entire env setup (including the hotfixes) and disable all replication agents
- Install the code package, verify if all packages are active and test the functionalities
- Verify the replication agents and configurations
- Update the deprecated APIs if any
- Install the index package if any custom index created
- If the instances are clustered, make sure you follow the order.

Answer (score 0):

For migrating content from old aem server to new version aem server we followed the below approaches. My answer is mainly focused on content migration.

1. First, take the content as a package from your old server.
2. Put the old content on your new server. And always you can maintain a back up of your old content as part of the package installation.
3. There are different approaches we took to migrate the old content to create a new tree that will be compatible with new structures/components.

Approaches:

1. Servlet with JCR API to change the content with a preferred logic.
2. Use the AEM Groovy console to change the content by using the groovy code. We preferred this in our project after knowing about this.
3. Always create a component that will fetch the data from the old content tree and it will show in new content tree. This is clunky and more preferable if you are going with completely new development. This will make you upgradable to next version without a major change. inthis case your old content will act like a DB for you.
4. Python scripts to do the same.
5. use json files to get and set the values to modify the JCR properties instead of going for big logic to map all the variables.
6. crx2oak is a tool to migrate the data, but I never used it in my project. you can check it out.
7. Let me know if you have any other idea to get it done

I have provided some answers here as well, checkout  : 
[Migrate AEM user generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50560749/migrate-aem-user-generated-content/58023732#58023732)

For coding migration upward migration can be enetertained because of aem's backward compatibilty, you just need to take the package and deploy into a new version instance. Some of the things might not work due to below reasons and you have to do some houskeeping  in this scenario after this you should be able to migrate code as well.

1. replace the quickstart jar file with new version jar. Start the jar.
2. keep looking into logs.
3. Make sure you get all AEM bundle configs.
4. Make sure you should have read/write access properly as er your old instance.
5. Create service users and all ACL permissions as per old instance.
6. Workflows need to be migrated.
7. core components resource path has to be corrected if there are any change in the new instance.
8. All 3rd party library from AEM has to be verified.
9. Check deprecated/incompatible codes, replace them and run.
10. Let me know I missed something

Comment: This (very old) question is about migrating applications between instances. Your answer is about content migration. You might want to clarify more in question's context.

Comment: Yes. Ofcourse my answer is mostly related to content migration, however if you look from a crxde perspective after deploying your code to aem it's a node which can be treated as content of you considered about migrating the code. Now coming to compatibility after migrating your code (/apps/project1) and content (/content/project1-content) this is something depends on adobe migration blog which will tell you how much impact it'll give you after migrating.