# Migrate AEM user generated content

Tags: java, aem

How to migrate AEM user generated content (UGC) from AEM 6.0 to AEM 6.3?

I am trying to make a UGC package  from aem 6.0 but unable to make it.? Can you please let me know the steps to migrate the UGC from 6.0 to 6.3 in AEM.

Comment: Please show evidence of what you have found/googled yourself. The first Google result from searching "migrate the UGC from 6.0 to 6.3 in aem" for instance?

Comment: https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-communities-ugc-migration   from this link I am trying... but it is not exporting the bulk pages , it export only one page.

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201244/rakhi4110  could you please provide your suggestion to performe above migration task.  Thanks, Gyanendra

Answer (score 0):

UGC is also saved as content node on AEM publishers so theoretically nothing different from other content node in the perspective of JCR.

The question is not that clear. I suppose you are trying to migrate all the content from AEM 6.0 to 6.3 including UGC.

In that case, you may simply create a content package in package manager at /crx/packmgr and then install the package on all 6.3 publishers.

Also, the usual use case for UGC in AEM is that there should be a reverse replication agent which replicate UGC content from publishers to author. If this is your case, you can also create the package in author, install on AEM 6.3 author and then replicate the package to all publishers.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** 
I know the following ways to migrate the data/content in AEM with same/different version.

1. Use CRX2OAK jar provided by AEM itself. Works with different server api as well.
2. Create and use servlet api to modify the data. In this step you have to create a package of your old content and put it into the same server where you want to migrate the data and your servlet api will be able to access the old data to modify as per your requirement.
3. You can use AEM default servlet apis which returns json for any node if you add .json at the last of your end-point urls. Make sure .json is not restricted in the dispatcher rules. ".html" extension should be replaced with ".json" extension. Use GET for reading, and POST for modification and so on.
4. Use AEM groovy console to write Java/Groovy scripts to do the same. Find the Doc at https://github.com/icfnext/aem-groovy-console
5. Moving content with siteadmin console is a way also, I don't know how much it may help you. You can move the content tree to update also the internal URLs automatically.

Please check out more at [AEM code and content migration from AEM 5.6.1 to AEM 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889399/aem-code-and-content-migration-from-aem-5-6-1-to-aem-6-1/58023489#58023489)

Do let me know if these options helped you, or if I am not able to understand your question by commenting.

**Old:** 
As per the previous answer, I am also not clear about your question!
But as I remember I got an issue while creating a package with dam folder file, it used to fail to create package with dam files. The error was NameSpaceException occurred while executing the dam files. It is pretty normal if you have old dam content and every dam content comes with some metadata. Some of the metadata are not recognized by AEM and need to register with a Namespace.

We were not clear how to handle this issue, so we went with following approaches. 
1. Exclude those files which are causing this issue. You might need to write some logic to find which dam files causing this issue(using groovy or servlet). 
2. Use CRX2OAK tool to migrate your data. 
3. Ask your dedicated adobe support team to replace the data using a snapshot update.